# Angular Animation, transition doesn't work with a single state

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have a problem with a gallery of div/cards developed in Angular 8.
I made a div/mask that contains a div/containerCards in relative position. Inside the div/containerCards I have the div/cards with % dimensions and positioned in absolute position. I see three cards at time and I have a button on the LEFT and other on the RIGHT, to move on the left or on the right the div/containerCards, changing values on "right" parameter.

The widget works fine but I have a problem with the transition, because doesn't work. I see on other examples that the transition need two states to work fine but my question is, is it possible use a transition with a single state?

In other words, how can I activate transition in my example/widget?

Thanks to all.

my `.ts` file:

```js
animations: [
  trigger('movement', [
    state('move', style({
      right: '{{rightValue}}'+'%'
    }), { params: { rightValue: '{{rightValue}}'} }),
    transition('* <=> *', [
      animate('1.6s')
    ])
  ]),
]

this.cards = [{
  name: "First card"
},
{
  name: "Second card"
},
{
  name: "Third card"
},
{
  name: "Fourth card"
}]

left() {
  this.rightValue = this.rightValue - 34;
}

right() {
  this.rightValue = this.rightValue - 34;
}

moveCallback() {
  let values = {};

  values = {
    value: 'move',
      params: { rightValue: this.rightValue }
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

my html:

```html
<div class="mask" [@movement]="moveCallback()">
  <div class="left-btn" (click)="left()">LEFT</div>
  <div class="containerCards">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of cards; let i = index">
      <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-btn" (click)="right()">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```css
.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 90px;
}

.left-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
}

.right-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 20px;
}

.containerCards {
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: It will be much more easier for other developers to help or give some advice if you create a repro of what you have and what you've tried on some online fiddler, like https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer and interest about. You can test my widget on this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fku48c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

To testing the widget and the problem with transition, you can click to this link of stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fku48c